# swiping left to change actvities in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get an app to swipe left and start a new activity I am just learning and have followed a tutorial. I don’t have enough point's to link it but I think I know what the problem is.

I can swipe left but it brings me to a blank screen with writing on top. Here is the MainActivity.java http://pastebin.com/Auj0Meb9

Here is my Main2Activity.java http://pastebin.com/2BXrzyYi I have commented out the piece of code that I get when I swipe left. What do I place here to make it show the full activity. Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: "What do I place here to make it show the full activity" -- um, `setContentView()`? As it stands, you have not defined any UI for your activity.

Comment: uncomment this line  //setContentView(Main2Activity); and provide a layout instead of Main2Activity. like you did in MainActivity

Comment: Thanks a million guy's. Worked first time.